# Convert position Transform to RectTransform

Tags: unity-game-engine, rect

I made a scene in Unity before release 4.6 using Transform and since release 4.6 I'm using RectTransform. My problem is that when I attach LocalPosition from value RectTransform to Transform it's a different position and scale. How to convert value from RectTransform to Transform?

Comment: problem it's fixed rect transfrom have same value with transfrom, my real problem it's parent position and child position

Comment: Please, convert your comment to full answer (with some code examples).